# While Loop in python is not working the way I intend it to

Tags: python, validation, while-loop

I have created code that will do a condition validation statement. I have a menu that prompts the user the enter a number between 1-3 and if the user presses any number besides those 3 numbers, it would tell the user an error message and loop the menu statement again until the condition is met. This is my code

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, make_response, abort
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
import myfunctions
import datetime
from myfunctions import create_connection, execute_query, execute_read_query, connection
from friend_insert import friend_insert
from movie_insert import movie_insert
from friend_delete import friend_delete
from random_movie import random_movie

while True:
    print("Press 1 To Add Friend Information")
    print("Press 2 To Add Up To 10 Movies Per Friend")
    print('Press 3 To Select Who Participates And Generate A Random Movie')
    choice = int(input())


    if choice == 1:
        friend_insert()
    if choice == 2:
        movie_insert()
    if choice == 3:
        friend_delete()
        random_movie()
        break
    
if choice != 1 and 2 and 3:
    print("Please Try Again")
```

The loop works. however, it is not showing the error message "Please Try Again." Why is that?

Comment: It's not showing because it's outside the loop.

Comment: when you fix that, you will notice that it will print the message even when choice = 2 or 3.

Comment: @NicholasHunter That's because the last if-statement is wrongly formatted. See my answer for a simplification.

Comment: Related: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [mre]. then look at your example - is there anything in your example that is not relevant to your question? or needed  by us to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The reason it doesn't work is that the last if-statement isn't in your while loop! Also, I'd suggest changing your if-statement format a little. Below is your corrected while loop:

```
while True:
    print("Press 1 To Add Friend Information")
    print("Press 2 To Add Up To 10 Movies Per Friend")
    print('Press 3 To Select Who Participates And Generate A Random Movie')
    choice = int(input())


    if choice == 1:
        friend_insert()
    elif choice == 2:
        movie_insert()
    elif choice == 3:
        friend_delete()
        random_movie()
        break
    else:
        print("Please Try Again")
```

This gets rid of the wrongly formatted `if choice != 1 and 2 and 3`. If you did want to do something like that, you'd have to do `if (choice != 1 and choice != 2) and choice != 3`; an else-statement is far more elegant, however.

Comment: Okay It works! Now I have another problem. I created a flask app that would run after that menu is executed but after the app runs, it would loop back to the menu

Comment: @kielp2 That is outside the scope of this question. I would suggest asking another one. Since my answer helped you, please consider accepting it!